# How to set a cookie with the secure flag in PHP?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

[image]I want to set the httponly and secure flag true in my code but when i am trying to set that cookie. In that case cookie is not created and am unable to login to site.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1); 
session_name('sim');
$_SESSION['nons']=rand(1,999999999);
$value=md5($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]." ".$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]." ".$_SESSION['nons']);
$_SESSION['sim']=$value;
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
```

This is the code which is using to create the session cookie after removing the below line code will work perfectly

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
```

But for security purpose i need to set the cookie flag one

Comment: I see your sessions, where are your `$_COOKIE`'s?

Comment: I am not use $_COOKIE basically i am using the above code to regenerate the value of default session cookie that is PHPSESSID

Comment: cookies are stored client-side, sessions are server-side.. I'm not seeing your cookie here ^

Comment: I am talking about session cookie which is generating by default in php

Comment: "In that case cookie is not created"  — Are you using HTTPS to load the site?

Comment: @sumitkundan only if enabled ^^

Comment: Why are you trying to assign values to session variables, _before_ you even started / picked up the session again?

Comment: [session_set_cookie_params()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) ? See the last 2 parameters.

Comment: @treyBake: please see in my quesition i have attached image which is shown cookie is set when i load the site

Comment: @Quentin: please refer the image which is shown in question.

Comment: @misorude: for security purpose

Comment: @sumitkundan anything before `session_start()` won't be set

Comment: @treyBake: then how can i set the flag for 1 for this session variable

Comment: @treyBake: As you see in the image there is httponly tag which show flase i need to make it true

Comment: _“for security purpose”_ is not a valid answer to the question why you are doing things in the wrong order … you need to start the session first, then assign values to session variables. (Your problem with the secure flag doesn’t even have anything to do with that part. That was just a general hint regarding a point of your code that currently doesn’t make much sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secure flag means "This cookie is only valid over HTTPS".

You are using HTTP (without the S).

This means the cookie is invalid and the browser is *correctly* ignoring it.

You can't require that cookies be secure if your communication channel isn't.